# Error en código Jquery JSON $.post()

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo este código que no consigo funcione, no pasa parámetros a la url destino.

~

```
**<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {     


    $("#loginBtn").click(function(evto) {  

            evto.preventDefault(); 

            var user = $(":text").val();
            var pswd = $(":password").val(); 

          $.post('./CRM/php/checklogin.php',            
                 { uname : user, psw : pswd },
                function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
                    if(statusTxt == "success")
                      alert("External content loaded successfully!");
                      alert("Retorno: " + responseTxt);
                    if(statusTxt == "error")
                      $("p.msg").append("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);              
                },
                'json'
      );     

    });

    $("#cancelbtn").click(function(){

       $.remove(function() {
            alert( "Bye now!");
        });
        window.close();                         
    });    

});

</script>


<form  id="loginform" action="./checklogin.php" method="post">
  <div class="imgcontainer">
    <img src="./CRM/img/avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <button type="button" id="loginBtn">Login</button>  

    <p class="msg"></p>    
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="">
    <button type="button" id="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
  </div>

</form>**
```

~

Alguien puede ayudarme, cual es el error?
desde el debug de FireFox veo lo siguiente

> *URL solicitada:http://192.168.21.128/S_crm/CRM/php/checklogin.php Método de la petición:POST Dirección remota:192.168.21.128:80 Código
>   de estado: 200 Host: 192.168.21.128 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
>   NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0 Accept:
>   application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01 Accept-Language:
>   es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
>   X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest Content-Length: 22 Connection:
>   keep-alive Referer: http://192.168.21.128/S_crm/ Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=hrrhjlejiee35vcdk9oohatuq6*

Gracias de antemano

Código php destino

```
    <?php 

    class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
        function __construct($it) {
            parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
        }

        function current() {
            return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
        }    
    }

    $jslogin = array();

    // connect to DB authenticate over unique user.
    // make PDOO method.

    include 'conexion.php';

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user_db, $pass_db);
      // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      // echo "Connected successfully: ";
      // Autentifica el usuario de app en la DB conectada
      // Utiliza función php password() function para encriptación
      // var de Form de autenticacion

        $username = $_POST['uname'];
        $passwd = $_POST['psw'];

    // tbl intervinientes.

        $tbl0 = "dbcrm_users";
        $tbl1 = "dbcrm_sec_usr"; 

    //   echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
      echo $username; 
    //   echo $_POST['uname'];
       echo $_POST['psw'];
    //   echo password_hash($passwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    //   echo "<br>";


        // select-join de los datos de usuario en la DB
        // utiliza prepare PDOstatement
        // Ordena el resultado descendente

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("select $tbl0.usr_name, $tbl1.pswd_date, $tbl1.Usr_passwd, $tbl1.pswd_int from $tbl0, $tbl1 where $tbl0.usr_name = '$username' order by $tbl1.pswd_date asc");

        // ejecuta la select con order by desc de el campo timestamp;

        $stmt->execute();

        // Num de filas afectadas sql
        // Si 0 no existe usr
```

Comment: Realmente no veo error amigo, por favor sube el HTML de tu formulario.

Comment: está en código, al final

Comment: Ok, hace falta tu PHP

Comment: Te subo la parte del php base inicial, en el puedes ver que no se resuelven lo campos del form en _POST.